# How do I tie Event Notification Service notifications to events in MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, webhooks, event-notification-service

We have just setup Event Notification Service and a callBack URL. I know how to tie messages called from the Transactional Messaging service, via the definitionKey. However, for other messaging that is initiated from MC itself, how can I tie messages back to a subscriber where there is no subscriberKey or message ID included?

Heres a sample of data that is returned:

```
info Message Key:

Eid: xxxxxxxx

Mid:xxxxxxxx


Channel:email

Composite Batch ID:61

composite List ID:60

Composite Sub ID:213995105

Info lp Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xx

user agent: Outlook-iOS/725.4611018.prod.iphone (4.38.0)

Composite ID:273670.60.61.213995105

Definition ID:NA

Definition Key: NA

Event Category Type: EngagementEvents.EmailOpen

Status:

Subscriber Key:

To:

Timestamp: 1590109543000
```

If anyone has any ideas about the fields that are returned then please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would leverage this field:

`Composite ID:273670.60.61.213995105`

This is to be JOBID.LISTID.BATCHID.SUBID

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you think SUBID is the subscriber ID?

Comment: @DavidB Yes subid would be subscriberid